# Invertible Matrix to Higher power

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on showing if A is invertible, that for any positive integer $n$, $(AMA^{-1})^n=(AM^nA^{-1})$

My first idea is induction on $n$ but is there a property of $A$ that explans why its power remains 1 or -1? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused - are you asking for help in a proof or "a property of A that explans why its power remains 1 or -1?"?

Comment: I'm looking for a proof of the first statement, my idea hinges on said property. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Induction would be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: look at this

$$
AMA^{-1} A MA^{-1}=AM^2A^{-1}.
$$